# Use phonegap or go native?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cordova

I'm about to make an application for ipad that has the following specifications:

- download JSON (or xml) from server
- download short audiofiles from server (locations are in the JSON from above)
- save these to the iPad for offline use.
- based on these files the user gets to do some exercises
- user progress/results need to be saved to the device so they can continue where they left off the next time they launch the app.

My question: Can this be done with only html/css/jquery Phonegap? Or should I go native and make this all in Objective-C? Or can I combine phonegap and Objective-C?

---

Now I'd like to know how I can save a json file on the device for offline use.
Also I'd like to know how to download audio (or images or whatever) and save those to the device.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with PhoneGap/Cordova and its HTML5 approach.

If it is iPad only, then go native.

Your app's high level requirements do not sound too complicated. For more complex apps always consider that facebook just went native for iOS because of their performance issues. In the end, this may be the way to go for a number of apps. PhoneGap or other HTML5 or cross compiling approaches for 1000+ devices plus native solutions for the market leaders.

Comment: In the end it will also be deployed to the play store for android devices so I recon Phonegap/cordova it is.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing application build in native Objective-C with applications build with Webtool like PhoneGap, in terms of being fast, Objective-C apps always win, but in terms of building it fast with zero knowledge of Objective-C Web apps win.

If you have knowledge of Objective-C, in my opinion go with native Objective-C app, else do it with PhoneGap.

BTW, those functionality mentioned in your question can be done with both.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what level UX your are aiming for and how you think your app may expand in the future.

If you need full control over the user experience, then you will need to go native. All the physics involved in scrolling/swiping will be done for you.  How much content will you have? if it's thousands of items then again native will offer the best performance. You can also perform certain tasks on background threads (my app did image compression and resizing before uploading the image, for example).

Otherwise - if you just want to get something out quick, go with phonegap.

**I speak as a developer who started out with Phonegap but went Native for performance reasons. Others may have had better experiences.*